# assert not working as expected

Tags: python, transcrypt

Here is the python code I transcrypted with **transcrypt -b -n -m** (version 3.6.84) :

```
def test_1():
    console.log('before assert')
    assert False, "False fails"
    console.log('we should not see that if assert fails as expected')


def test_2():
    console.log('before assert')
    try:
        assert False, "False fails"
    except AssertionError as exception:
        console.log('we should see that since we catch the assertion error')
    console.log('after assert')
```

When I run test_1/test_2 in the browser console, I get a strange behavior :

```
> mymodule.test_1()
before assert
we should not see that if assert fails as expected
<- undefined
> mymodule.test_2()
before assert
after assert
<- undefined
```

Why no exception are raised with assert ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer from [issue 482](https://github.com/QQuick/Transcrypt/issues/482) :

You need the -da switch to activate assertions:

> transcrypt -b -n -m -da

I've tested:

```
def test_1():
    console.log('before assert')
    assert False, "False fails"
    console.log('we should not see that if assert fails as expected')

def test_2():
    console.log('before assert')
    try:
        assert False, "False fails"
    except AssertionError as exception:
        console.log('we should see that since we catch the assertion error')
    console.log('after assert')

try:    
    test_1()
except AssertionError as exception:
    console.log('we should see this')

test_2()
```

It prints:

```
before assert
we should see this
before assert
we should see that since we catch the assertion error
after assert
```

Many things in Transcrypt are optional, to prevent bloat of the generated JavaScript.
Some features are controlled by command line switches:

http://www.transcrypt.org/docs/html/installation_use.html#available-command-line-switches

Some features are (also) controlled by pragma's (compiler directives):

http://www.transcrypt.org/docs/html/special_facilities.html#the-pragma-mechanism